# Using local git repository with Ansible Tower

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower

I have been successful configuring Ansible Tower project to pull from remote git repos, and also pulling from a local repo using ssh and stored credentials (keys). On this server, allowing ssh login to access git is not acceptable, so I am trying to configure Ansible Tower to use a local git repository; not using git: or ssh: protocol to access, just accessing it via file:///path/to/AnsibleTower.git

The Ansible Tower project-update function tries to 'git clone', but it gives an error:

```
        "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.",
        "Please make sure you have the correct access rights",
        "and the repository exists."
```

And it shows this is the command it used to attempt to clone:

```
"cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin file:///path/to/AnsibleTower.git/ /var/lib/awx/projects/_114__00_test"
```

When I execute the above command directly on the server, as the `awx` user, I get no error and the clone works. I can see that the git commands is being executed with the `awx` user when Tower attempts to update (watching ps for the process). The `awx` user owns the AnsibleTower.git directory and everything in it.

The reason this is important and the reason I have tagged this 'ansible-inventory' is that using an SCM-backed project seems to be the only way to import/synchronize a text-based inventory to Tower. I would really like to avoid re-creating/updating my inventory using the Tower web interface; I want that tracked in SCM as well.

I even went so far as to grant all users access to the .git directory (temporarily); that didn't work either, it doesn't seem to be a user-permission issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible Tower is only able to locally access playbooks and associated files from `/var/lib/awx/projects`.

If the repo is presented as a file folder, you can link from `/var/lib/awx/projects` to the repo like this:

```bash
ln -s /my/great/repo /var/lib/awx/projects/repo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the file:// at the begin of the origin.
All local repositories do not need this and some OS cannot handle file:// uri‘s for local files/directories

Comment: I tried removing file:// but no change. The error is exactly the same; no worse.